# Trying to Iterate through multiple page Star Wars JSON feed and store values in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I am trying to hit the Star Wars API and store the values of the character names in a list. I am using .append, but it is only storing the names from the last page. I have tried both a list and a dictionary to store the names. The API is paginated.

I am trying to be a very basic character search tool that returns the character info, if the character exists. I am using Python 3.6 in Spyder via Anaconda on a Mac. Appreciate any guidance.

Thanks.

```
import requests 
import urllib.parse

#number of pages in JSON feed
page_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in range(len(page_list)):
    try:
        pages = page_list[i]

        endpoint = "https://swapi.co/api/people/?"

        type = 'json'

        #specifies api parameters
        url = endpoint + urllib.parse.urlencode({"format": type, "page": pages})
        #print(url_2)

        #gets info
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        number_of_char = json_data['count']

        #list to store names
        st_names = []

        count = 0
        while count <= number_of_char:
            print(json_data['results'][count]['name'])
            st_names.append([json_data['results'][count]['name']])
            count = count + 1

#error handling 
    except KeyError:
         print('Key error \n')
         pass
    except IndexError:
        print('Index error \n')
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared list inside the loop so it gets overridden in each iteration. So  declare your list outside the for loop.

Comment: Wow, did not notice that. Thanks! It works now, of course.

Comment: Please add an explanation, now it is more a comment instead of an answer. [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Since I declared the list inside the loop, it was rewriting itself and overriding the first iterations.

Pulling the declaration outside the loop fixed this problem.